# Make a click event in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm  trying to make a click from server side.

I'm using nodeJS and I'm not able to use JQuery function.

I would make click on the `.next` class.

This is what I would do :

```
while (nbrPage > 0)
{
    //my scraping code
    nbrPage--;
    $('.next').click();
}
```

Note than the html code to scrape is like this :

```
<span class="next">
     <a id="nextPage-159c6fa8635" class="page" href="/blablabla"></a>
</span>
```

Does anyone know how to use JQuery methods in NodeJS code or how to make click function in NodeJS ?

EDIT: I'm scraping a website and I want to loop on each pagination and scrap my data from each page. For this I need to go on the next page and click on the html code below. In other words I would use JQuery functions like `$('.next').click()` in my node js code (using `request` and `cheerio`).

Note than I don't want to handle the click event, I'm looking to make the click.

Thanks for your help

Comment: And why isn't jquery working?

Comment: You can't `click` on a link because you don't have a DOM.  You'll need to evaluate the `href` attribute from each anchor tag and devise a function to resolve the reference, fetch it, and feed it into your scraper.

Answer (score 0):

Cheerio is a pretty useful tool which allows you to utilize jQuery within Node.JS. You can find more information over at - https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

> Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http
>   calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

Check out their documentation - https://github.com/request/request

For server-side, you need to create a function to find the a href with the id that started with "nextPage-". Then IF found you will need to get the value of the attribute href.

From there you would pass that value back to your "request" script, which I assume you already have and continue your scrapping till a "nextPage-" could not be located anymore.

That repetitive sequence of a function calling itself is called "recursion".

Now for what that might look like in code -

```
// Load Dependencies
const CHEERIO = require("cheerio");
const REQUEST = require("request");


/**
 * Scraps HTML to find next page URL
 *
 * @function getNextPageUrl
 *
 * @param   {string} HTML
 *
 * @returns {string || boolean} Returns URL or False
 */
function getNextPageUrl(HTML) {

    // Load in scrapped html
    let $ = CHEERIO.load(HTML);

    // Find ID that starts with `nextPage-`
    let nextPage = $("span[id^='nextPage-']:first");

    // If it is 0, its false
    if(nextPage.length) {
        // Return href attribute value
        return nextPage.attr("href");
    } else {
        // Nothing found, return false
        return false;
    }

}


/**
 * Scraps the HTML from pages
 *
 * @function scrapper
 *
 * @param   {string} URL
 *
 * @returns {string || boolean} Returns URL or False
 */
function scrapper(URL) {

    // Check if URL was provided
    if(!URL) {
        return fasle;
    } 

    // Send out request to URL
    REQUEST(URL, function(error, response, body) {

        // Check for errors
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           console.log(body) // Show the HTML

           // Recursion
           let URL = getNextPageURL(body);
           scrapper(URL);

        } else {
          return false;
        }

    });
}


// Pass to scrapper function test
//console.log(getNextPageURL("<span class='next'><a id='nextPage-159c6fa8635' class='page' href='/blablabla'></a></span>"));

// Start the initial scrapping
scrapper("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Thank you @Blake for your answer, unfortunately I've one more problem. You're solution should work but I'm friendly scraping a supermarket website. When I go for the first time at the url I have to set the location and chose the supermarket I want, and if I use its url I don't have to set the location each time I use the url but when I use urls from the next tag the also redirect me to the select your location page... Do you know how can I do to fixe it ? I hope to be clear enought.

Comment: I understand. I would like to see the URL from after the 'select your location' page. Maybe we can predict the way the other pages will be formatted.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to do it in Node.js. Node.js is server side, not client side.
As a solution, you can parse **href** at the link and make a request to scrap the next page. This is how the server-side scrappers usually work.